# How to get a list of user's purchased apps on android?

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app that will manage user app purchases and installation.
As I have understood there is no Google API for Google Play Store available.

How can I get the "My Apps" list from the Google Play Store and not only the list of install apps?

Thanks